# How to disable Video playback controls?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have already successfully hidden the playback like this `controller.showsPlaybackControls = false`, but this does not actually disable the controls. I can still drag around in my View to change the Video playback.
Is the an easy way to disable these controls?

I have this Custom Video Player:

```
    struct CustomVideoPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var player: AVPlayer
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false
        
        controller.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(context.coordinator, selector: #selector(context.coordinator.restartPlayback), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: CustomVideoPlayer
        init(parent: CustomVideoPlayer) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        @objc func restartPlayback() {
            parent.player.seek(to: .zero)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the right way to do it, but for now I got a working solution. I just added `.allowsHitTesting(false)` on my `VideoPlayer`.

Comment: Well this leads to other problems, like tapgesture not working